# Facebook verification can't validate my ID

Tags: facebook, account-management

I used my nickname as my middle name and my maiden name, and now I'm locked out of my Facebook account. I did not know that this was not allowed according to the Facebook Terms of Service. When I try to verify my identity with my driver's license, it says it can't validate.

I need to have my Facebook account back only to access my pictures. I have irreplaceable pictures of my family that I want very much not to lose. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved, and how long did it take? I've waited more than a month with no reply.

Comment: FaceBook = Stinking Shit. I had my REAL name on facebook since 2010. In 2019 I got my facebook hidden and locked, and I cannot log in. they ask of me to identify my account with other browsers that are now of a newer version and that are not anymore in use. So I cannot that way. Also they asked of me to send in my ID, I sent in now over 7 times of my passport, still NOTHING. They ask of phone verification, but I never get a code on my SMS although the phone number is correct. I quadruple checked it. I got email verification, it worked but still did not get account back. After all these years.

Comment: So join WorldTruth.MX it is like FaceBook but without the facebook shit that the facebook assholes put me through after 9 years of being loyal to their community page. Fuck you facebook, after 9 years this is what I get, shit directly into my face, just because I may have posted some news articles government officials do not like people to say.

Answer (score 3):

You're not by any means the first person that has been locked out of their Facebook account. In order to deal with such occurrences Facebook has created a webpage called **Disabled Accounts**.

1. Go to the [Facebook Desktop Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/) webpage.

2. If you can't access your Facebook account you should see pictures on the Facebook Desktop Help webpage that look like the screenshot below. You have to be logged out of Facebook in order to see this picture. Click the light brown button that has: *Get Info About Disabled Accounts* underneath it.

[image]

3. This will take you to another Facebook webpage called **Disabled Accounts**. This webpage has a lot of information about how to re-enable a disabled Facebook account. Look for the link on this webpage called *My personal Facebook account is disabled*. Click on the arrow to the left of where it says *My personal Facebook account is disabled* to unfold the text beneath it so you can read it.

4. In the unfolded text beneath the *My personal Facebook account is disabled* heading there is another link that may be of interest to you called *submit an appeal*. If you think your account was disabled by mistake you can click on this link to submit an appeal. Submitting an appeal is something that you can do in case you think that your problem is being handled incorrectly by computers, and you want someone to give personal attention to re-enabling your disabled account.

Comment: When i go to sign in it says it has to open a browser then it wants to send a verification txt (i dont have that phone # any more and since i never add my phone for txting didnt think it mattered .but affter trying this multible times did the appeals one Finna

Comment: Finally got it to accept my id and it pops up that i have to  llist an email address that has been disabled???? So i retyped it fought it a few more times with the id BAm same thing about the email address

Comment: Now you're in the loop with a computer, and it's automatically rejecting everything you submit. I think you need to find a way to get a human being involved. I'm sorry, but I don't know what to do if you try to submit an appeal, and then they block you off because you no longer have a nonexistent email address. Facebook has a step-by-step article in _Desktop Help_ -> _Manage Your Account_ -> _Account Settings_ -> _Editing Your Settings_ that tells you how to add a new email address, but you have to be already logged in to Facebook, of course.